# Example of coverage in LibFuzzer on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2022, libfuzzer

I try to find some information how to run some example code:

```
bool FuzzMe1(const uint8_t* Data, size_t DataSize) {
    return DataSize >= 4 &&
        Data[0] == 'F' &&
        Data[1] == 'U' &&
        Data[2] == 'Z' &&
        Data[3] == 'Z';  // :‑<
}
```

```
extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t * Data, size_t Size) {
    FuzzMe1(Data, Size); //Example
    //FuzzMe2(Data, Size); //Example
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to receive coverage information of result like in this website:
https://github.com/google/fuzzing/blob/master/tutorial/libFuzzerTutorial.md
[image]

but,I receive this result:
[image]

I working on Windows and VS 2022.

Comment: Looks like something is wrong in your code and it is actually not running anything as `exec/s` says 0 in the output you attached. And as per https://llvm.org/docs/LibFuzzer.html#output `Each output line also reports the following statistics (when non-zero)` cov might be 0 in your case.